# What is the alternative to Ajax.BeginForms in Asp.net MVC core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I think in asp.net MVC core we no more have the option to use  Ajax.BeginForms .. so what is the alternative for Ajax.BeginForm ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use inline `data-ajax-*` attributes :

```html
<form method="get"
      data-ajax-="true"
      data-ajax-method="get"
      data-ajax-url="/test">
      ...
</form>
```

- `data-ajax`
- `data-ajax-url`
- `data-ajax-method`
- `data-ajax-mode`
- `data-ajax-update`
- `data-ajax-loading`
- `data-ajax-loading-duration`
- `data-ajax-confirm`
- `data-ajax-begin`
- `data-ajax-complete`
- `data-ajax-failure`
- `data-ajax-success`

See [Ajax Request Using Inline Attributes](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/AjaxRequest) for some samples

Or you can call `$.ajax` from inside `<scripts>` tag:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

See [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/mjebrahimi/AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax

1. Install nuget package called: AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax
2. In startup in ConfigureServices add the following line `services.AddUnobtrusiveAjax(useCdn: true, injectScriptIfNeeded: false);`
3. In razor page place `@Html.RenderUnobtrusiveAjaxScript()` at the end of body and after jquery
   Example of using instead of `Ajax.BeginForm` call:

   ```
   using (Html.AjaxBeginForm("SendComment",
   new AjaxOptions
   {
       HttpMethod = "Post",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
       UpdateTargetId = $"comments{Model.ExerciseId}",
       OnBegin = "ExerciseScripts.toggleLoading($(this), $(this));",
       OnSuccess = $"ExerciseScripts.toggleLoading($(this), $(this)); $('#textarea{Model.ExerciseId}').val('');",
       OnFailure = "Notice.showError();"
   }))
   {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
       @Html.Hidden("exerciseId", Model.ExerciseId)
       @Html.TextArea("Comment", "",
           new {
               id = $"textarea{Model.ExerciseId}",
               @class = "form-control",
               placeholder = "Write you comment",
               required ="required"
           })
       <br />
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
           <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o fa-lg"></i>
           <span>Send</span>
       </button>
   }
   ```